# Can I open VS 2008 Project in VS 2010 Beta

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I was hoping there would an option somewhere that would just let me open my VS 2008 projects and continue working in .Net 3.5 - while using some of the neat new VS UI enhancements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Visual Studio 2010 allows you to target previous versions of the CLR/.NET framework at the project level.

When you open the Visual Studio 2008 project file in Visual Studio 2010 it will convert the project file for you.  Once this is done, it will be smart enough to target the proper framework and runtime version for you (.NET 3.5 and CLR 2).   If it doesn't, you can change this yourself on the property sheet for the project.

Comment: One thing to watch out for is that while you will still be able to open the project in VS2008, you will get MSBuild warnings about an "invalid ToolsVersion" value. It's safe to ignore it, but you will see it. Also, if VS2010 converts the **solution** file, you won't be able to open that solution in anything other than VS2010.